# React-select & creatable select with reatc-hook-form focus on validation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using create select components inside a react-hook-form. I have tried the react-select and creatable-react-select both and the behaviour I experience in context of this issue is the same.

Using latest react-hook-form (7.6.1), I can't set the field to be focussed when there's an error bound to the field.
[CODE SANDBOX EXAMPLE FOR THIS](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-react-select-controller-with-focus-forked-ys4r4?file=/src/index.js)

When I use an older version of react-hook-form, I can get this behaviour to work as expected.
[CODE SANDBOX EXAMPLE FOR THIS](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-react-select-controller-with-focus-forked-ys4r4?file=/src/index.js:1488-1514)

As i want this behaviour to work in the latest react-hook-form, any suggestions on what is the problem in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using controller for react-select component but did not use prop "field" from "render" method of Controller, therefore, the ref element is not set in order to help react-hook-form to set focus.

Working sample: [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-react-select-controller-with-focus-forked-9gb9t?file=/src/index.js)